# Add leading zeros to incrementing Jquery dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to modify a date dropdown in sharepoint, as by default the minutes dropdown only allows you to select 5 minute intervals. I had gotten it working initially using the below code:

```
$("select[id$='DateTimeFieldDateMinutes']").empty();

var newOptions = {00: "00",
  01: "01",
  02: "02",
  03: "03",
  04: "04",
  05: "05",
  06: "06",
  07: "07",
  08: "08",
  09: "09",
  10: "10",
  11: "11",
  12: "12",
  13: "13",
  14: "14",
  15: "15",
  16: "16",
  17: "17",
  18: "18",
  19: "19",
  20: "20",
  21: "21",
  22: "22",
  23: "23",
  24: "24",
  25: "25",
  26: "26",
  27: "27",
  28: "28",
  29: "29",
  30: "30",
  31: "31",
  32: "32",
  33: "33",
  34: "34",
  35: "35",
  36: "36",
  37: "37",
  38: "38",
  39: "39",
  40: "40",
  41: "41",
  42: "42",
  43: "43",
  44: "44",
  45: "45",
  46: "46",
  47: "47",
  48: "48",
  49: "49",
  50: "50",
  51: "51",
  52: "52",
  53: "53",
  54: "54",
  55: "55",
  56: "56",
  57: "57",
  58: "58",
  59: "59"
};

var $el = $("select[id$='DateTimeFieldDateMinutes']");
$el.empty(); // remove old options
$.each(newOptions, function(value,key) {
  $el.append($("<option></option>")
     .attr("value", value).text(key));
});
```

I've tried to clean it up and optimize it some by doing the following:

```
$("select[id$='DateTimeFieldDateMinutes']").empty();
$(function(){
    var $select = $("select[id$='DateTimeFieldDateMinutes']");
    for (i=0+0;i<=59;i++){
        $select.append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(i))
    }
});
```

However, when I do this I lose the leading zero in the html value. Is there anyway to do this or am I stuck using my clunkier method?

Comment: Have you tried [left-pad](https://www.npmjs.com/package/left-pad)? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just transform to string and add a 0 if i<10

```
$(function(){
    var $select = $("select[id$='DateTimeFieldDateMinutes']");
    for (var i=0; i<=59; i++){
        var strnum = (i<10?"0":"") + i;
        $select.append($('<option/>').val(strnum).html(strnum))
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked perfectly. Javascript isn't my language of choice so I didn't even think to make it a string...duh.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a check if it is less than 10 to add a leading zero.

```
$("select[id$='DateTimeFieldDateMinutes']").empty();
$(function(){
    var $select = $("select[id$='DateTimeFieldDateMinutes']");
    for (i=0+0;i<=59;i++){
        var min = i < 10 ? '0'+i : i;
        $select.append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(min))
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom pad function:

```
var pad = function (n) {return n<10? '0'+n:''+n;}
for (i=0+0;i<=59;i++){
    $select.append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(pad(i)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`0+0` is effectively a string. If you increment it, JavaScript will try to parse it to a number or return `NaN`.

Instead of doing this, change to:

```
for (i=0;i<=59;i++){
  var padded = i < 10 ? "0" + i : "" + i;
  $select.append($('<option></option>').val(padded).html(padded));
}
```